# opening Sublime Text 3 opens sidebar by default

Tags: sidebar, sublimetext3

I usually use Sublime Text 3 with the sidebar toggled off but every time I reopen Sublime, I see for a second that the sidebar is not there but then it opens up.

What code can I place in my User Settings that will make the side bare remain hidden?

---

### UPDATE 1

My installed packages are:

- Advanced New File
- Autoprefixer
- Emmet
- HTML5
- Jade
- Jade Snippets
- Jquery Mobile 1.4 snippets
- Jquery Snippets pack
- Mongomapper Snippets
- Package Control
- PyV8
- Sass
- Sass Snippets
- SFTP
- Sidebar Enhancements
- Stylus
- Sublime linter contribe jslint
- Theme Flatland

I'm thinking the culprit could be either Sidebar Enhancements or Theme Flatland. I should also mention that when I open Sublime Text 3 I am opening it as a Sublime project. Not sure if that could be forcing the sidebar to open. This is what is in my `projectName.sublime-project` file:

```
{
  "folders":
    [
      {
        "follow_symlinks": true,
        "path": "."
      }
    ]
}
```

---

### UPDATE 2

I just closed my current Sublime project and opened up a single file, edited it, closed the sidebar, saved the file and closed Sublime. Upon reopening Sublime, the sidebar was closed. Now I am pretty sure the culprit is the fact that I am opening a Sublime project. There is some Sublime project code or setting that is force opening the sidebar upon launching Sublime in project mode but I've no idea where that could be located.

Comment: Do you have any packages installed that might cause this?

Comment: @idleberg I updated my question adding the list of my installed packages and the fact that I am opening a sublime project when I open sublime. It's not just one file I am opening

Comment: @s3z try disabling packages one by one to find the culprit.